# Page.setVersioned(false) but still serialized. Why?

Tags: wicket

I have single page application (all AJAX) and thus don't need page versioning. So I do `setVersioned(false)`. However, the page is still serialized on each AJAX request and I would like to know why.

The Wicket version I use is: 7.6.0

**WicketApplication.java**

```
public class WicketApplication extends WebApplication {
    public Class<? extends WebPage> getHomePage() {
        return HomePage.class;
    }
    public void init() {
        super.init();
        getFrameworkSettings().setSerializer(new MySerizalizer("foo"));
        System.out.println("SERIALIZER: " + getFrameworkSettings().getSerializer().getClass().getName());
    }
    static class MySerizalizer extends org.apache.wicket.serialize.java.JavaSerializer {
        public MySerizalizer(String applicationKey) {
            super(applicationKey);
        }
        public byte[] serialize(Object object) {
            final byte[] serialize = super.serialize(object);
            System.out.println("serialized " + String.valueOf(serialize.length) + " bytes of " + object.getClass().getName());
            return serialize;
        }

    }
}
```

**HomePage.java**

```
public class HomePage extends WebPage {
    public HomePage() {
        final Label label = new Label("message", new PropertyModel<>(foo, "bar"));
        label.setOutputMarkupId(true);
        add(label);
        label.setVersioned(false);
        final AjaxLink<Foo> ajaxLink = new AjaxLink<Foo>("plus1") {
            public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
                foo.inc();
                target.add(label);
            }
        };
        ajaxLink.setVersioned(false);
        add(ajaxLink);
        setVersioned(false);
        System.out.println("VERSIONED: " + isVersioned());
    }

    private Foo foo = new Foo();

    class Foo implements Serializable {
        int bar = 0;
        public String getBar() {
            return "bar is " + String.valueOf(bar);
        }
        public void inc() {
            bar += 1;
        }
    }
}
```

**HomePage.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>home page</h1>
        <span wicket:id="message">Message goes here</span><br><br>
        <input type="button" wicket:id="plus1" value="add one"></input>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Log:**

```
SERIALIZER: com.foobar.WicketApplication$MySerizalizer
VERSIONED: false
serialized 2286 bytes of com.foobar.HomePage
serialized 2499 bytes of com.foobar.HomePage
serialized 2499 bytes of com.foobar.HomePage
serialized 2499 bytes of com.foobar.HomePage
serialized 2499 bytes of com.foobar.HomePage
```

For each click on the button (`org.apache.wicket.ajax.markup.html.AjaxLink`) the page gets serialized. Why if it is not versioned?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but afaik a page needs to stateless to not be serialized by default in wicket. Since you're page is using ajax components it has to be statefull.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only stateless pages are not stored. Page versioning is controlling whether a page instance could have several versions in the store.

Since Wicket 7.4.0 it is possible to [make the Ajax components and behaviors stateless](https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/guide/7.x/single.html#_stateless_ajax_components_behaviors) too!

Comment: Finally I disabled serialization like this:
http://maciej-miklas.blogspot.de/2013/09/wicket-6-disable-page-serialization.html
However it also disables page caching. If you still need cashing (which I do not), this one looks interesting: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14823293/how-can-i-disable-serialization-in-wicket-1-5/39846343#39846343

Answer (score 1):

For documentation about stateless AJAX see https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/guide/7.x/single.html#_stateless_ajax_components_behaviors